# Объясните пожалуйста как выглядит куча из массива

Tags: массивы

Объясните пожалуйста как выглядит куча из массива, в интернете описано размыто.
Пример:
Является ли "кучей" массив {23,14,17,12,13,10,1,5,7,6}

Answer (score 1):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

согласно этому определению - нет, приведенный массив не является кучей

```
{23,14,17,12,13,10,1,5,7,6}
```

должно было бы выглядеть так к примеру:

```
23 -> {14, 17}
14 -> {12, 13}
10 -> {7, 6}
7 ->  {1, 5}
```

или так:

```
23 -> 17 -> 14 -> 13 -> 12 -> 10 -> 7 -> 6 -> 4 -> 1
```

т.е. если отсортировать массив и превратить в список